# Should I still continue to plant a potato that turned green?

Tags: plant-health, potatoes

When potatoes are exposed to the sun they turn green and become toxic. I wanted to try to chit a potato tuber but I'm scared that when it turns green I will end up harvesting green tubers as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Potato tubers turn green as a response to sun exposure to help protect themselves from being eaten so they can reproduce.

Plant it and it will proceed naturally to do what was intended, grow a new plant and shrivel up as it delivers the stored energy to it.

Keep the ground mulched under the plant so no new tubers are exposed to the sun and all the new tubers will be their natural, non-sun exposed selves in whatever color the variety produces, ready to eat.